# Angular: How to do SEO for dynamic pages?

Tags: angular

I know there have been several similar questions, but I cannot figure out the way to go for this specific example.

I have an Angular SPA. When you open page.com/post/abc, it will fetch the post data of post "abc" from our server and display them, that is: Image, caption, username, time posted, comments, etc. The "raw HTML" without the dynamic content from our servers is just an empty placeholder for the post.

These pages are not shown on any search engines at all and I want to change this. I compared this to reddit. When you see Reddit on Google, it usually is a URL like this: reddit.com/r/subreddit/comments/25563a/visiting_for_3_days_what_should_i_do/
So it gives the ID (in this case 25563a), but it also appends the post's title to the URL - I guess for SEO. I would like to do it similar to Reddit: I want out post pages to show on search engines too, with such a URL, and with other post data taken into account too, such as username and the caption.

Can someone give me hints or links how to do this? I am okay with keeping things simple, the data Google has for indexing the site doesn't need to change when the user edits the post or comments are added. It can stay the same as it was when the post was published.

Comment: did you try to use angular universal for server side rendering?

Comment: Link for more info about SSR in Angular https://angular.io/guide/universal

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to inject the Meta Service into the component:

```
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';
...
constructor(private meta: Meta) {}
```

so you'll have the variable `meta` available, and add as many as you want. You can do so like this:

```
this.meta.addTags([ 
    { 
        name: 'description', 
        content: 'This is a description for the component' 
    }, 
    { 
      name: 'keywords', 
      content: 'your, keywords, go, here' 
     }
]);
```

Comment: Without SSR or SSG the search engines will not see this..